# Add an initial view (front page) with a tab bar application (Xcode 3.2.5)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, view, tabbarcontroller

I have created a tabbar application from the default templates. I want to add a frontpage that has a picture, the title of the App and that will not include the tab bar, and which will not have a tab on the tab bar.

This would be the first page that someone sees when launching the App, and would have an "Enter" button leading into the firstviewcontroller ideally i.e. the first tab of the tab bar.

I cannot find how to do this at all - have explored Splash screens (but understand this is not what it's meant for). And all the codes that may work don't seem to be for XCode 3.2.5.

Is there a tutorial out there?

Any help much much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [Loading a Welcome Screen (Splash Screen) before TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029102/loading-a-welcome-screensplash-screen-before-tabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: [Loading a Welcome Screen(Splash Screen) before TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029102/loading-a-welcome-screensplash-screen-before-tabbarcontroller)

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a go with it and if it works will tick the green tick thing.

Comment: Okay, had a look - the other issue I am having is that all these tutorials say "put it in the applicationdidfinishlaunchning, but in this template it is application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Is that the same thing?