# Splash Screen (Welcome) before Tab View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to program an iOS App in Swift, where there would be a splash screen before the tab bar screen.

I've looked at:

- http://sweettutos.com/2014/01/08/present-a-login-screen-before-the-tab-bar-controller-in-a-uitabbarcontroller-based-app/
- [Loading a Welcome Screen (Splash Screen) before TabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029102/loading-a-welcome-screensplash-screen-before-tabbarcontroller)

but both of them require a nib file and I did all my UI in storyboard.

Here's my main question:
The code on the website has something like this:

```
ControllerName(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil);
```

Is there any way I could do the same thing without the nib file and use storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the `TabBarController` already in storyboard, you would add another view controller next to it.

[image: View Controller Object]

Then you would click on the new view, and in the attributes inspector, check off "Is initial View Controller".

[image]

That makes that new view the first thing that comes up when the app is opened. To go to the tabBarController, I would probably have some button on that first view that just has a segue(control drag) to the `TabBarController`.

Comment: Or automatically transition after like a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following the example in which the tab bar view controller is set as initial viewcontroller you can

1. Drag and drop another UIViewController from the Object Library into the storyboard [object library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osQcs.png).
2. Click on the UIViewController and assign it a StoryboardID
   [StoryboardID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWrXS.png).
3. In your first view controller class you can access the storyboard and create an instance of the new view controller, that you dragged and dropped before, using the storyboard id, you can do it this in the viewDidAppear override function and present the new view controller modally.

   ```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { 
   let myStoryboard = self.storyboard
       let modalViewController = myStoryboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ModalViewControlllerID")
       presentViewController(modalViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate programmatically a viewController from a storyboard in a similar way as you would do from a xib with `ControllerName(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil)`, it's:

```
UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerName")
```

But you must not forget to set the arbitrary identifier of your viewController in the storyboard under **Storyboard ID**:
[image: Storyboard ID in Interface Builder]

Answer (score 0):

Drag navigationController and viewController to storyboard and make navigationcontroller as initial viewcontroller then push tabbarcontroller from viewcontroller.

Thanks,
Nada Gamal

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do the same for my project. Here is my solution.

I created a ViewController and made it the Storyboard Entry Point in the Main.storyboard. I previously had a TabViewController with all kinds of setup and needed only 1 change there.

TabBarController should have a StoryboardID, I named my "TabBarID".

I created a new LaunchViewController swift file with that new ViewController added to my Main.storyboard and assigned it in Main.storyboard.

Here is that class. Very simple with a timer that once over the threshold will then present the TabBarViewController in fullscreen.

```
class LaunchViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer = Timer()
    var time = 0
    var threshold = 2
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundTheme(theme: .orangeWhite)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        time += 1
        if time > threshold {
            timer.invalidate()
            guard let storyboard = self.storyboard else {
                //failed to find storyboard
                return
            }
            
            let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TabBarID")
            tabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            present(tabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```